# certutil -addstore -user -f Root gives error_access_denied, although run as admin

Tags: windows, certificate, certutil

Trying to install a certificate file (xxx.cer) to the user's root certificate list with the following command

```
certutil -addstore -user -f Root .\xxx.cer
```

results in the error message

```
CertUtil: -addstore command FAILED: 0x80070005 (WIN32: 5 ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
```

I'm running this from an elevated admin prompt. Trying to install the certificate through the mmc-gui results in the same error message. Running it via `psexec -i -s` as system account works, but then, of course, the certificate is not in the user's context.

Trying to install the certificate on any other pc works fine, so the file is ok. `sfc /scannow` doesn't bring up any errors either.

Any idea what I could do to fix this?

Comment: So the certificate is just a [root] CA file? Is it possible that the affected PC/user account has some smartcard or secure USB stick software installed which tried to install the cert on the smartcard/USB stick which is not present?

Comment: Yes, exactly: this is just the root CA file of the certificate issued by a local ssl server and no smartcard/USB stick is involved in this case. Don't ask me about details _why_ the software handles it in this way, but this is part of government software that just works this way and can't be messed with.

Comment: OK, I understand, this is part of the installer script of that government software. Have you checked Windows event log on that PC where it fails?

Comment: @Robert: Just checked it - there was nothing. But in preparation to send you more data I found the solution... Thank you for thinking into this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the registry key Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Root\ProtectedRoots where the user had no access to - read is required. For some reason there was an "unknown" user SID in the access rights to this key. Removing this and adding the correct user fixed the issue.

I found this by running procmon on certutil.exe. This revealed an "access denied" result when it tried to read this registry key.